# JavaScript Button Switch

Tags: javascript, css, button

I'm trying to make a simple mobile website, the goal is to have a div I can click on to open up a div underneath it. The html is set up with 2 div's on top of each other and the CSS for the bottom div's display is set to 'none'. In the javascript there's an event listener waiting for the click then setting the display to 'block' and opening the bottom div. How do I make the same action (re-clicking the top div) set the bottom div's display back to 'none'.

current basic code:

```js
document.getElementById('divOne').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('divTwo').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#divOne {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#divTwo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOne">Click me</div>
<div id="divTwo">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `display: block` is set on the element.

```js
document.getElementById('divOne').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var divTwo = document.getElementById('divTwo');
    if(divTwo.style.display === 'block') {
        divTwo.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        divTwo.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

```css
#divOne {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#divTwo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOne">Click me</div>
<div id="divTwo">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the display is `none` earlier then switch it to block or vice versa. I am storing the DOM Object of the element in a variable to keep it clean.

```
document.getElementById('divOne').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var divtwo = document.getElementById("divTwo");
  divtwo.style.display = divtwo.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```